# Firebase - Calculate metrics based on daily event count

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I am using Firebase Analytics on my iOS/Android apps.
I have custom events for certain actions for example.
"**place_order**" and "**place_order_fail**".

These numbers are not consistent and in the process of minimizing the place_order_fail events I want to see my progress. But the events are different every day depending on traffic and active users.

So 100 place_order_fail events one day is the same as 200 place_order_fail on a busy day.

Is there a way to create a custom metric that calculates for example

> place_order / place_order_fail + place_order

which would be the success rate per day etc.
I can't seem to find anything on the Firebase Console.